# Changing one language font to another font

Tags: unicode, fonts

I have something typed like this "usGefaemfh emrnf armitatmifyg;".

They are all correctly typed according to another language font and it should actually look like this "ကျွန်တော့်နာမည်မောင်အောင်ပါ" (this is in Burmese font).

I have a document containing a lof of "usGefaemfh emrnf armitatmifyg" and I want to convert all them to Burmese unicode font. Is it possible? I have tried font conversions and searched online but nothing works so far.

Comment: What you want is not a Unicode font, you simply want to use some *non-standard font* for that text. Apparently it uses normal ASCII code points, but in the font file those are mapped to Burmese character shapes. Therefore you can't specify "use this font for Burmese" anywhere, since the text isn't Burmese, it's just "English" with weirdly shaped letters.

Comment: Is there a way to quickly get around this? It will be a huge pain in the a** to have to retype everything in Burmese. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you know what English letter maps to what Burmese letter, you could do a general find-and-replace to get actual Burmese text… No, there is no quick fix. That's what happens when you don't adhere to standards…

Comment: Ah, that's good-enough advice. I didn't think of it. I will just do find and replace.

Comment: Seek for [transliteration](https://python-myanmar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/romanization.html) or [romanization](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/693688/ROMANIZATION_OF_BURMESE.pdf)… Or [MY-AKKHARA: A Romanization-based Burmese (Myanmar) Input Method](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/my-akkhara-a-romanization-based-burmese)?